# How can I match strings except for another string pattern in regex?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

How can I match strings without another string?

Example strings:

```
foo bar qux    Expected Result: MATCH    (`foo` & `bar` without `skip` or `ignore`)
foo            Expected Result: NO MATCH (`foo`, without `bar`)
bar baz qux    Expected Result: NO MATCH (`bar`, without `foo`)
foo bar skip   Expected Result: NO MATCH (`foo` & `bar`, but also `skip`)
ignore foo bar Expected Result: NO MATCH (`foo` & `bar`, but also `ignore`)
baz qux        Expected Result: NO MATCH (not `foo` & `bar`)
```

Regex:

```
/(?=.*?\bfoo\b)(?=.*?\bbar\b)((?!skip|ignore).)*$/gi
```

Here's a Regexr sandbox: https://regexr.com/4t4lo

Yes, there are several similar questions, but nothing I've been able to work into this simple sandbox.

Comment: Use `^(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?=.*\bbar\b)(?!.*(skip|ignore)).*$`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. Does that work for you in regexr? I cannot get it to match the expected results above.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, the proposed answer does not get me any closer to answering this question. Did I miss something?

Comment: It fully answers your question. You missed `.*` in the negative lookahead and a `^` anchor at the start. [Works wonders](https://regex101.com/r/wZdM0v/1).

Comment: Thanks. Also I had `gi` instead of `gm`.